# Git custom merge to handle configuration files

Tags: git, merge, config, app-secret

So I was searching for a way to handle the configurations file in a git projet. I read some articles about the subject but all of them where suggesting a second, local-only file. And that doesn't feel right to me.

So I messed around with some of the git commands to find a way to achieve things another way.

A way I found this could be possible may be like this :

## Files

The config for the example is a simple `key : value` list inside a file.

The `local` state is the lastest pulled version of the template :

```
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
```

The `remote` state is the version on the repository :

```
1 : 1
a : 2
3 : 3
4 : 4
```

On this file I have one new field : `4` and a modified field `a`.

Finally the `working` state is the configuration file used by the application. It is a copy of the `local` file modified with the secret values for running the application. This version should not be pushed to the repository.

```
1 : secret1
2 : secret2
3 : secret3
```

## Flow

Here is the workflow I thought about :

On `pull`/`checkout` :

- backup the `working` file into a separate file to prevent being rewritten;
- do a merge on the `local` and the `remote` to get the last configuration template;
- somewhat merge the `local` and the `saved_working`.

The last merge should provide user a display for the new field to add, as long as not overriding the existing fields values.

An example of such operation may be :

1st merge :

```
-    2 : 2
+    a : 2
+    4 : 4
```

2nd merge :

```
1 : secret1
-    2 : secret2
+    a : 2
3 : secret3
+    4 : 4
```

And now, before being able to use the application again, we clearly see the lines to changes.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an application should be able to read many configuration files, and only a default configuration file should be stored in the repository; for example:

1. read /path/to/the/app/default.conf
2. read a system-wide /etc/application.conf
3. read user configuration (ie: ~/.config/application.conf), if it is in the same directory than the application, use a [.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Some projects (like [ansible](http://ansible.com) with [Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_vault.html)) store an encrypted version of the configuration file, that could be a solution too.

Would it work for your setup?

Another suggestion would be a separate branch where you [cherry-pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the code or the configuration, depending your preferences.

**Edit:** precisions about cherry picking.

This was just a suggestion, it's like your toughs about merging, except you choose which commits you want to get from the "remote".

On your machine, working in the `local` branch:

1. `git fetch`
2. either `git merge master` or `git cherry-pick` the commits you want

Nothing ground-breaking, I'm not sure if you expect the operation to be automated or manual.

Comment: I agree with you about the multiple configuration file part, but I really wanted a way to do without ... Can you explain a little more about the cherry-pick part please ? :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to think thoroughly WHY you do need to store config file in the repo? If that's some default option set then it probably should be integrated into project (maybe compiled into binary; IDK what your project is). If that's a sample option set then you needn't using it in your working tree so just ignore it when pulling. Anyway the software shouldn't be unusable when config file is missing, it should have some default values therefore you won't need to merge your working config with the repo's version.

I used to keep my configs in the repo but later changed my mind and removed all these commits. Config is a changeable state referring to user preferences; code repo is for storing the history of the code. Mixing these two subjects seems bad practice to me.

**upd**

If you don't want to support upgrading config from older verison to a recent one there is just one way I can imagine:

- Store config template in the repo
- Add a tool to the repo that upgrades actual config from previous version to the recent one (it could be a small program or even better a script)
- Set this tool to launch on post-pull event.

So every time a dev pulls from remote repo, the config tool would be updated too and then launched. Tool committed in a revision upgrades actual config file from exactly the previous version to a recent version that was introduced in this revision. Obviously plain text tool is more preferable here (for tracking changes) but binary will work too.

Comment: The case here is that when multiple people are working on the same projet with different environments, they need to specify it somewhere. So the config file is useful. The only want we have from a config file is the template, so we want to share the template and not the actual configuration inside it

Comment: @Nobe4 yes, as I thought. So you want to have a skeleton of config to be shared between devs. It is the case when I'd advice integrating it inside your project. In most cases changing the config template involves code change: dialogs, file read-write, using new options and so on. So the config template becomes an integral part of the project's code as new template will be useless without new code and new code will fail without new template. In this case the template should be pulled along with other codebase and loaded internally in specific way unlike the usual custom configs are loaded.

Comment: Exactly, but wen we integrate a configuration, it must suit everyone's configuration. So some values needs no change across the different environments...

Comment: @Nobe4 I don't see why a **new** code should be unable to deal with older config. There's one more idea I've added to my answer above